# How to correctly run queue for huge processes (import large excel file)?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, worker

My command **php artisan queue:work redis --queue=process --tries=0 --delay=2 --timeout=120 --sleep=5 --memory=2048**. But I noticed that the file is looping in it. Can you share yours or give a link to some in-depth source? There is little information in the official documentation.

*I add a large file and there are situations when the file is looped, mainly when adding a file with the queue turned off. And after its launch, the file begins to be added endlessly.*

[image]

Comment: "But I noticed that the file is looping in it." define that

Comment: Could be your job is failing and retrying, try to add --tries=1